# Boundedness in $L^{\infty}$ and convergence a.e. implies boundedness of the limit in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Boundedness in $L^{\infty}$ and convergence a.e. implies boundedness of the limit in $L^{\infty}$.

Are there mistakes in my proof, and is the assertion correct? The proof feels too simple and I couldn't find the statement anywhere online.

Let $g_n:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded sequence in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that $g_n\rightarrow g$ a.e. Then $g\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

$\sup_{n}|g_n(x)|\leq \sup_{n}\|g_n\|_\infty\leq C$ a.e.

Since $g_n\rightarrow g$ a.e.  $\sup_{n}|g_n(x)|\geq|g(x)|$ for almost every $x$.

$\|g\|_\infty=\inf\{K>0:|g|\leq K a.e.\}\leq \inf\{K>0:\sup_n|g_n|\leq K a.e.\}\leq C$

Edit: I changed the title to the correct question, thank you for the answer!

Comment: Note that the statement in your question and the statement in your title are different. "Then $g$ is in $L^\infty$" is different from "convergence in $L^\infty$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in your title is false. For example, $g_n(x) = 1_{[n,n+1)}$ is a sequence of functions which is bounded in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and converges to $0$ a.e. but does not converge in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ since $\|g_n - 0\|_\infty = 1$ for each $n$.

However, the statement you provide in the question (which does not say that $g_n \to g$ in $L^\infty$ but only that the limit $g$ is in $L^\infty$) is true and your proof of this is indeed correct.

Comment: Very helpful, does that mean that $g_n$ converges to $g$ weakly? or is that something entirely different.